# Having trouble listing my data in alphabetical order in a linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I want to list my data in alphabetical order with the following method. However, names and surnames are not listed on a regular basis. Looking forward to your help and suggestions. Thanks.

```
var tempData = Payrolls
.Join(Users, pyr => pyr.UsersId, usr => usr.UsersId, (pyr, usr) => new { pyr, usr })
.Join(UserRegisters, usr => usr.usr.UsersId, urg => urg.UsersId, (usr, urg) => new { usr, urg })
.OrderBy(p => p.usr.usr.UserSurname)
.ThenBy(p => p.usr.usr.UserName)
.OrderBy(p => p.usr.pyr.SalaryMonth)
.ThenBy(p => p.usr.pyr.SalaryYear)
.Select(p => new
{
    PayrollId = p.usr.pyr.PayrollId,
    PersonnelId = p.usr.pyr.UsersId,
    IdentNumber = p.usr.usr.IdentNumber.Decrypt(),
    PersonnelName = p.usr.usr.UserName.Decrypt(),
    PersonnelSurname = p.usr.usr.UserSurname.Decrypt(),
    SalaryMonth = p.usr.pyr.SalaryMonth,
    SalaryYear = p.usr.pyr.SalaryYear,
    WorkerRegNo = p.urg.WorkerRegNo.Decrypt(),
    NetPaid = p.usr.pyr.NetPaid2
})
.Take(100)
.ToList();
```

I have tried different ways with `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`. End of transaction
... When I write with `OrderBy`, it gives error in `String.Decrypt` in `Decrypt()` method, especially when sorting encrypted areas. For example:

```
....
OrderBy (p => p.SlaryMonth)
...
ThenBy (P => p.UserName.Decrypt ()) <--- throws an error when I add this place.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Be careful when tagging. C and C# are apples and oranges

Answer (score 2):

You've used `ThenBy` to do subsequent ordering, but then chained on a new `OrderBy` after that, which starts a new ordering and discards the previous one. You need to change your second `OrderBy` call into `ThenBy`:

```
.OrderBy(p => p.usr.usr.UserSurname)
.ThenBy(p => p.usr.usr.UserName)
.ThenBy(p => p.usr.pyr.SalaryMonth)
.ThenBy(p => p.usr.pyr.SalaryYear)
```

Finally, if sorting by `Decrypt` throws an error, it's pointing to a problem in your decryption, not the sorting.

Answer (score -1):

Alphabetical sorting does not occur regularly when I do the following method.

```
var tempData = Payrolls
.Join(Users, pyr => pyr.UsersId, usr => usr.UsersId, (pyr, usr) => new { pyr, usr })
.Join(UserRegisters, usr => usr.usr.UsersId, urg => urg.UsersId, (usr, urg) => new { usr, urg })
.OrderBy(p => p.usr.usr.PersonnelSurname)
.ThenBy(p => p.usr.usr.PersonnelName)
.OrderBy(p => p.usr.pyr.SalaryMonth)
.ThenBy(p => p.usr.pyr.SalaryYear)
.Select(p => new
{
    PayrollId = p.usr.pyr.PayrollId,
    PersonelId = p.usr.pyr.UsersId,
    IdentNumber = p.usr.usr.IdentNumber.Decrypt(),
    PersonnelName = p.usr.usr.PersonnelName.Decrypt(),
    PersonnelSurname = p.usr.usr.PersonnelSurname.Decrypt(),
    SalaryMonth = p.usr.pyr.SalaryMonth,
    SalaryYear = p.usr.pyr.SalaryYear,
    WorkerRegNo = p.urg.WorkerRegNo.Decrypt(),
    NetPaid = p.usr.pyr.NetPaid2
})
.Take(100)
.ToList();
```

.OrderBy (p => p.usr.usr.PersonnelSurname)

If I add Decrypt to the line
The 'System.String Decrypt (System.String)' method did not support translation into SQL. I get an error.

I believe that the sorting problem is caused by the fact that the encrypted parts of the data cannot be converted during sorting. At this point I need to ensure that the encrypted data is normalized so that I can ensure the correct sorting takes place.

the way I use to convert encrypted data is as follows

```
public static string Decrypt(this string cipherText)
{
    var cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

Comment: I find this unclear - is this a question, or an answer?

Comment: I tried to ask questions. On the other hand, I reopened the question. Because I made a few changes to the codes.